# What am I missing in my script file? (line by line copy to the interpreter works)

Tags: python

I'm working on the coursera data science course and making my first foray into python, and while respecting whitespace is driving me bonkers it's not too bad.

Even if there's not enough here to diagnos my problem maybe a savvy python programmer can open my eyes to the gottcha's I'm not even aware enough to google.

I've been trying to debug my script for some time to no avail. All the files and such are loading just fine but when I try and process a bunch of stored tweets and score them with a sentiment dictionary I get scores when I use the python interpreter but all zeros with my script. The difference is that in the script I put the execution chain in main() but at the CLI I'm executing line by line (though I did set up the relevant get_score function).

What I believe are the relevant lines:

```
import sys
import json
import re

parse_words = re.compile("\W")
data = []
dictionary = {}

...

def get_score(tweet_text):
    words = parse_words.split(tweet_text.lower())
    word_scores = map(lambda word: dictionary.get(word, 0), words)
    score = sum(word_scores)
    return score


def main():
    """set up the data files"""
    ...
    for i in range(len(data)):
        try: # because not each line contains a tweet
            tweet_text = data[i]["text"].encode('utf-8')
        except:
            tweet_text = ""
        print("%6.2f %s" % (get_score(tweet_text), tweet_text))
```

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine, you should post the whole script.

Comment: what is the score of a word? the number of times it appears in a tweet?

Comment: Try not to use raw `except` blocks.  Instead catch the specific exception which you reasonably expect as a result of the input.  To debug, try using `except Exception, arg` and printing the contents of `arg` in the exception handler.